# Fancy compositing not working in lualatex

Tags: fonts, opentype

I am using an OpenType font that can combine symbols from two adjacent words.  This works fine in LibreOffice Writer, as shown on the left in this image.  The line-with-circle is drawn above the part that looks like a table.  But the same font file used with LuaLatex, and the same text input, results in the mess on the right with the two parts superimposed.  Do I need to enable some package or feature for LaTeX to properly interpret the instructions embedded in the font?  I already am including 'fontspec'.

The font in question comes from http://musilili.net/linja-pona/ version 4.9 and the input text to generate this case is "supa+lape".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\tpf{linjapona49}
\begin{document}
{\tpf supa+lape}
\end{document}
```

SIngle characters from the same font work with no problem.

[image: Good and bad compositing]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the actual LuaLaTeX code you're using. Ideally, you'd post a [compilable minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the issue you wish to fix. Please also state which TeX distribution you employ and when you last updated it.

Comment: Also tell us which of the several versions of the font you’re using.

Comment: Is your TeX installation up to date? I get correct output from your minimal example.

Comment: lualatex -v reports "This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)"

Comment: I just checked the ubuntu updates and no later luatex is in the stream.  If I need later I will have to get it directly from the development site.

Comment: I see a version 2.01 at the French SVN site though the latest prebuilt binary they offer is 1.13.

Comment: texlive 2019 is a bit old (especially for lualatex opentype font handling which has a lot of development, obviously for pdftex things more stable)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092 The paper by egreg is very helpful.

Comment: If you don’t want to install TeX Live without Ububtu’s package manager, you can upload the font to an Overleaf project and use a 2021 luatex there: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qmwvbddysjmd

Comment: I don't mind getting a new texlive without ubuntu.  I remember it was a quite large package at the time.  It is best to have the latest for this sort of hting.

Comment: WOw, those instructions are old.  I will have to do some research.

Comment: [This](https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/) looks promising.

Comment: Those instructions worked.  I am now at lualatex 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) and the compositing is now correct.